# Error with bash do loop - error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

The following code gives me an error when I run it, I can't see where I have went wrong.

I have looked up man as well.

```
while [inotifywait -m -r -e modify -e move -e create -e delete '/home/client/Files' ]; do
    echo "File Notification" | mail -s "Client File Notification" -t "test@test.com"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

`[` is a command that do a test. You did not want to test something about inotify, but want to test the result of that command. so bracket `[ ... ]` is too much. You have to write:

```
while inotifiwait ... ;do
```

or better

```
while array_answer=($(inotifywait ...)); [ "$array_answer" ] ;do
    echo Event is: ${array_answer[0]}
    echo file is: ${array_answer[1]}
    ...
    done
```

Comment: Good point; I saw the missing space after the `' '`, but didn't notice that the command shouldn't be between square brackets in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`[` is actually a command name, a synonym for `test`, so you need whitespace before and after it.

Change this:

```
while [inotifywait ... ]; do
```

to this:

```
while [ inotifywait ... ]; do
```

Without the space, the shell will probably try to execute a command called `[inotifywait`, which presumably doesn't exist. (You should have shown us the error message in the body of the question; I didn't initially notice that you quoted it in the title.)

(Note that it's ok for the `;` to immediately follow the `]`, since `;` is a shell metacharacter.)

Comment: And as @F.Hauri's answer correctly points out, the `inotifywait` command shouldn't be between square brackets in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

While F. Hauri is right about the mistake in the while condition, that doesn't explain the "error near unexpected token 'done'" error. There's nothing in the commands you posted that'd cause this error, so I suspect you may have invisible characters in the file, possibly carriage returns at the end of the lines (they're the norm for Windows/DOS text files). Try viewing the script with `cat -v` and look for "^M" at the end of lines, or anything else weird.

If the problem is errant carriage returns, use `dos2unix` to remove them, then switch to a text editor that doesn't add them in the first place.

Comment: That's a common problem under Cygwin. Many Cygwin commands can handle DOS-style line endings, but the shell doesn't; it would treat `done^M` as a command name, where `^M` is an ASCII carriage return character. A copy-and-paste of the error message would be helpful. Note that `dos2unix` replaces its input file, unlike most Unix text filter commands.

Comment: Thank's for all you're help, I am new to shell scripts so I didn't know about the [] bracket test case.

The problem that was causing my error was I was using Notepad in Windows mode, I switched it to unix mode and it fixed the problem.

Thanks Again!